# Como identificar o usuário no Ratchet PHP

Tags: php, cookies, websocket

Estou criando um chat de múltiplas salas com websockets, utilizando Ratchet PHP. O próprio framework facilita o processo de identificação do usuário, buscando o seu nome através de cookies, como pode ser observado aqui: http://socketo.me/demo.

No meu ambiente local (localhost) não consigo estas informações. Acredito que seja algum problema com os cookies. Como posso fazer para pegar estes dados com cookies para identificar o usuário em ambiente local?

Comment: deves tentar salvar um cookie localmente para ver se esta salvando...

Comment: Olá Lauro, obrigado pela resposta.
Sim, estou gravando meu cookie localmente, porém ele não faz o envio. Já testei a gravação do cookie tanto em PHP como em Javascript, utilizando a biblioteca Jquery Cookie.
No meu cliente, faço a gravação do cookie e abro a conexão utilização a sessão do AutobahnJS, conforme explicado nos tutoriais de Ratchet. Mas o meu servidor não recebe o valor do cookie gravado. Acredito que seja uma particularidade do ambiente local.
Como poderia fazer o envio? Falta alguma informação na abertura da sessão do Autobahn?